# How to find which pages do I pass in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow. I have a main page that is called "X" and I want to create a log record for which pages is passed by the users untill reaching my main pages that is "X".

My question is how can I find which pages is passed by users when they are in "X" page ?. 
Is webflow providing any future for this problen?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: So you don't want to log the pages as the user goes through them, only log them all after they've reached page X? If so, I don't think there's any way to ask WebFlow after the fact which states it's gone through to get to this one. You'll have to keep a history yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `getPageName()` avaliable according to Spring API.

Take a look [here](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0/api/net-1.1/html/topic8733.html).

You could just save the visited pages into an array and make a `count++` each time the page is visited.